# Ajax +wordpress onClick link redirect to new page and create html content

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax, hooks

i have two pages in my wordpress plugin

- index.php
- charts.php

in index.php i have some content and some link..

```
 <a onclick="show_trend()" >Trend</a>
```

while clicking this link ,i have an ajax function to create content in charts.php(i dont know if it is correct way)

```
function show_trend() {
 var data ="action=render_admin_charts_page";
   jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {

                      alert(data);
                     //here i want to create html content

                    }
                });

}
```

andfollowing is my php function and hook

```
function render_admin_charts_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="chart">

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
     die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
```

now i am getting 0 as alert .

Comment: your data var should be an object: data = {action: 'render_admin_charts_page'}; Currently you just send a string (action=render_admin_charts_page), while WordPress ajax handler is looking for $_REQUEST['action'], which is not set in your case. See line 26 in wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: @ungestaltbar can u elaborate and post as an answer?

Comment: Where did you define your `render_admin_charts_page` function?

Comment: in charts.php      .

Comment: The issue could be either as pointed out by ungestaltbar or your AJAX function not being called. If charts.php is your plugin file then it should work otherwise you should define the function in theme functions.php file.

Comment: @sri i want to render in wp admin

Comment: @sri as ungestaltbar said i hv changed to object

Comment: I think you should define the function in index.php if that is your main plugin file. It works for me this way. But someone else can enlighten me if it is otherwise the case!

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to create content in charts.php when clicking a link in index.php? If you are moving away from index.php to charts.php on click then I don't see a need for Ajax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15506/discussion-between-sri-and-nisham-mahsin).

Answer (score 1):

I see two things. You're missing an action call - you need

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page');
```

Plus, from looking at your `render_admin_charts_page()` you need to change your json dataType to html. Your charts function is outputting html so all you need to do is output it; your `alert()` should contain all the html from your function.

One more thing, if this is still a live question, why `die()` in your `render_admin_charts_page()` function? That function prints a message so that could also be messing with your returned value.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, kaiser. This is a lot easier to read. Still getting the hang of this

Answer (score 0):

As ungestaltbar said, the variable "data" should contain an object, not a string.

```
function show_trend() {
   var data = {
       action: "render_admin_charts_page"
   }
   jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {

                      alert(data);
                     //here i want to create html content

                    }
                });

}
```

That should do it.

Comment: this chage makes nothing!